# Argument of type '"==="' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WhereFil terOp'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I'm trying to create a where clause for a firebase collection reference:

```
this.allItineraries = firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection(`itinerary`);
```

Here is the where clause:

```
      return this.allItineraries.where('userId', '===', this.userId);
```

But the program won't compile and gives the following error:

> [ng] ERROR in src/app/services/data.service.ts(45,55): error TS2345:
>   Argument of type '"==="' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'WhereFil

The where clause looks identical to what I've seen in the firebase examples.

[image: The actual firebase collection]

Comment: Does it work with "=="? I have not used angular fire, yet, but I see the docs support "==". 
  https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries: *The comparison can be <, <=, ==, >, >=, or array_contains*

Comment: When I change it to '==' I get the following:

ERROR in src/app/services/data.service.ts(49,7): error TS2322: Type 'Query' is not assignable to type 'CollectionReference'.
[ng]   Property 'id' is missing in type 'Query'.

Comment: I also tried this:
      const ref = this.allItineraries('id');
      return ref.where('userId', '==', this.userId

and get the following error;

ERROR in src/app/services/data.service.ts(49,19): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Coll
ectionReference' has no compatible call signatures.

Comment: .where() returns a Query, not a CollectionReference.

Comment: That was it, @JB.  I needed to cast that query to another variable then use .onSnapshot on the query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was trying to use the query on the collection reference.  I had to create a query from the collection then use that query for the onSnapshot method.